# USB mouse/keyboard stopped working ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit

Tags: usb, mouse

I have Logitech easy call desktop set. (http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/136)

I've recently changed my graphic card from nvidia to ati this usb set stopped working in ubuntu 12.04 after that..

I think it's not a hardware problem because i have dual-boot, and it works perfectly in Windows 7.

If I run `lsusb` the devices seem to be connected. If I connect an extra mouse to any usb port it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please _post_ the `lsusb` output instead of only mentioning it. Also try unplugging your mouse/keyboard (I assume this is wireless) receiver then plug it back in, and run `dmesg | tail -n 20` or so and [edit] your question to add the output.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I found the problem, when enabling additional drivers for my new ati graphic card the usb mouse and keyboard stops working.. The system gets very unstable. So i just disabled it and it's ok now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When enabling additional drivers for my new ati graphic card the usb mouse and keyboard stops working.. The system gets very unstable. So i just disabled them and it's ok now.